# Set max string size for MySQL SELECT result

Tags: mysql, select, size, limit

I want to limit the max size of a MySQL SELECT using PHP. I could some sort of iteration with PHP, but that would be less efficient. Is there a way I can set the maximum string size or byte size of something to return? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want limit the amount of data returned by your query? Even for something like `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want to limit the data selected, and then displayed. As in, MySQL should ignore all entries where one field is larger than some amount of bytes or characters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT SUBSTR(myString, 1, 10) as myString from myTable
```

**EDIT:**

Then you want

```
SELECT myString from myTable where length(myString) < 11
```

You also have `char_length` and `bit_length`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want MySQL to just not select any entries over some amount of characters or bytes.